# ExtJs: TextArea how to return value as an array instead of as a string?

Tags: extjs, extjs6, extjs6.2

On ExtJs 6.2, I have a form with a TextArea.
When user inputs text on several lines, for example :

```
line 1
line 2
```

The binded value is currently a string :

```
value= "line 1↵line 2"
```

But I need to send value (to server) as an array, when the store is submitting.

How to tell to the textarea to return input text as an array ?

```
value : ["line1", "line2"]
```

without to have to split string as array on the server-side.

**Edit**: I dont't want just to split value. Because I would to update the default behavior of the textarea to avoid to have to apply the split (in ViewController) each time that I using it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have created a fiddle with how I would approach it (assuming I have understood your requirements correctly!)

https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/1uq7

This example turns an array into a string when coming into the textarea, and splits it on the way out.

```js
Ext.define('ArrayTextArea', {
    extend: 'Ext.form.field.TextArea',

    alias: 'widget.arraytextarea',

    setValue: function(val){
        // if it's an array then join with a newline
        if(Ext.isArray(val)){
            val = val.join('\n');
        }

        return this.callParent([val]);
    },
    getValue: function(){
        var val = this.callParent(arguments);

        // split the value by newline char
        return val.split('\n');
    }

});
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. Thanks you.

Answer (score 2):

document.getElementById('textarea').value.split('↵')

Comment: Why you are using document.getElementById if you can use Extjs's method

Comment: I would to store the internal value as an array but without impact on the display value. I tried to override the default behavior of setValue and setRawValue value but when I split value as array, display value is automatically override like this `line1, line2, line3`

Comment: @tejas - this was just example. You can use whatever method you want.

Comment: @vianney -just store its value in some variable then manipulate with it.
Also, you could make example in fiddle, it would be much easier to help you if we can reproduce your problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can use standard way provided by sencha http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/5.0.0/api/Ext.form.field.TextArea.html#placeholder-simple-getValue
Check this and reply.

Comment: I search rather to change the default behavior of textarea to be sure that, in all screens of my application, bind values on textarea are array and not string.